# Off topic migration option gone

Tags: bug, status-completed, migration, off-topic

When voting to close as `off-topic` no migration paths appear.

[image]

Comment: This issue seems to be happening again at the moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem fixed by the elves in the SE factory.

Comment: elves are awesome