# Why doesn't the off-topic flag allow you to pick from any of the sites?

Tags: discussion, support, flags, migration, off-topic

On many occasions, I've found questions that should be moved to AskUbuntu, or Unix/Linux, but when I click the "flag" link, I don't have those as options. I hate to leave something flagged as off-topic with no suggestion of where to put it, so I just cancel.

1. What determines the sites that show up on that list?
2. Is it best to flag them off topic even if the ideal site doesn't appear?

Comment: [Related to this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68437/off-topic-migration-option-gone), but that question claims it was addressed.  Is meta now the only site with **no migration options**?

Comment: possible duplicate of [When Voting to Migrate an Off-Topic Question, Why Is the List of Sites Limited?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79960/when-voting-to-migrate-an-off-topic-question-why-is-the-list-of-sites-limited), [List of target sites in flagging wizard](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84902/list-of-target-sites-in-flagging-wizard), [Add cstheory.stackexchange.com to the list of site for “off-topic” questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77074/add-cstheory-stackexchange-com-to-the-list-of-site-for-off-topic-questions)

Comment: About 75% of the time, the questions aren't good enough to justify migrating to another site in the network. Remember that the cardinal rule of migration is **don't migrate crap**. Just vote to close as "off-topic" (the generic one that doesn't migrate--that's what it's there for).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was discussed in [More Options When Flagging for Migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96205/more-options-when-flagging-for-migration). Quoting Jeff:

> There are only 5 blessed migration slots, of which 1 is dedicated to
>   meta.
>
> **This is a "Don't Make Me Think" barrier; we don't want to present
>   closers with a list of 12 different destinations and make them suss
>   out which one is correct. There should be 4 most frequently correct
>   destinations + meta.** If you believe a pet site deserves a place in
>   that list, prove it with data of existing closed questions, not blue
>   sky "what if there were.." imagineering
>
> If you feel strongly a question belongs on a site that isn't listed,
>   then there is a way to do this -- flag them for moderator attention
>   instead!
>
> Can you make a case that these Unix questions are more prevalent than
>   one of the other 4, and should displace it in the list? Do you have
>   data to support this, in the form of a giant list of closed questions
>   that belonged on {x} site?
>
> (I am also disinclined to randomly migrate questions in the network
>   unless they are of good quality, and *strong* fits to the target
>   site.)

Personally, I flag them as "other" and include where I think they belong in the message to the moderators.