# Why am I sometimes not allowed to select an off-topic migration destination?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, migration, vote-to-close

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Closing question as off-topic has no options to move to another site (main SO)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152655/closing-question-as-off-topic-has-no-options-to-move-to-another-site-main-so)

I've noticed this a lot recently, that when there are already close votes on a question, it sometimes doesn't give me the option to go further into the off-topic menu and select a destination for migration (similar to [this very old question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68437/off-topic-migration-option-gone)). For example:

[image: Selected off-topic as close reason]

This question won't let me go further into the dialog. I've selected the off-topic reason and nothing happened. I realize that with 2 votes as off-topic now, it's no longer eligible for automatic migration, but it also did this when there was only 1 vote for off-topic. In this case, it would still be possible for a super-majority automatic migration.

Out of curiosity, I tried selecting off-topic on a random question which had no close votes, and the migration destinations appeared as expected.

Is this a new feature that was implemented? A bug in the close dialog? What's going on here?

Comment: You're very active on meta. How did you miss this?

Comment: @Mysticial: I have no idea, where was it? o.o

Comment: @animuson [Here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151890/disable-migration-for-questions-older-than-60-days).

Comment: Bleh... Anna beat me to it.

Comment: On that note, we could make this an FAQ-proposed?

Comment: Ah. I see. October 18 was during the timeframe I was working 60 hours/week at the Election Commission. :/ I didn't spend much time on SE during that period. Look at the things you miss in such a short period of time!

Comment: @Mysticial: can't we just edit the flagging / migration faq? Not that I can find one..

Comment: @Martijn: do it.

Comment: @Shog9: My better half is going to do something dreadful to me if I start that now.. tomorrow maybe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot select a destination when the question is over 60 days old: [Disable migration for questions older than 60 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151890/disable-migration-for-questions-older-than-60-days).